# How to pass additional values on tab change event with angular mat-tabs in angular 2?

Tags: angular, tabs, material-design, onchange

I am using angular [material.io tabs](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview#keyboard-shortcuts) in my project like this. But I am just able to get the label of the selected tabs on change of the tab, I want to pass custom data (AllTabData variable) on change event, so that I can change the global variables using shared service, or retrieve relevant data from server based on tab selection.

```
         <mat-tab-group (selectedTabChange)="onTabChange($event)">

               <mat-tab  *ngFor="let tabname of tablist"  label="
          {{AllTabData[tabname]['Name']}}">

                      <!---tab content --->

                </mat-tab>

         <mat-tab-group>
```

In component, I have onTabChange Function like this

```
 public onTabChange(tabChangeEvent: MatTabChangeEvent): void {
        console.log(tabChangeEvent);
    }
```

Here is what I got in console with tabChangeEvent var,

[image: console data]

Comment: Well you have your tabs in only one component, I don't get your issue ... Can't you just bind your desired value to a variable in that component ?

Comment: Ok let me explain in another way, I have a data table on each of the tabs, I want to display different values in the data table (header,data,footer) for each different tab. So On tab change event I want to retrieve the data based on selected tab and for that I need to pass more parameters and not just a label.

Comment: @trichetriche so You mean to say that I should Hold one variable in my component where I can access desired values based on label as the key. Something like array with key as label. Am I right?

Comment: Kind of, all I mean is that since you only have one component, you can simply create variables that hold your data/metadata and call them on demand ! If you want something simple, simply call your variables by the name of your labels, and use them with `this[tabChangeEvent.label]`

Comment: @trichetriche Cool,  I am trying to do it, Since The variable That is holding metadata is not in having label as the key. And lable is just another metadata. So I have to rearrange the variable or create a new one where key is label.

Comment: As I said, it's up to you, do what you're most comfortable with :)

Comment: @trichetriche can you give an example of how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

in the component.html

```
<mat-tab-group (onTabChange)="onTabChange($event)">
   <mat-tab
      data="thisIsMyData"
      *ngFor="let tabname of tablist"
      label="{{AllTabData[tabname]['Name']}}">
                      <!---tab content --->
   </mat-tab>
<mat-tab-group>
```

and get the data in component.ts

```
public onTabChange(tabChangeEvent: MatTabChangeEvent): void {
    let mydata = tabChangeEvent.tab._implicitContent.getAttribute("data");
    console.log(mydata);
}
```